# Jupyter Notebook default directory setting in windows 10 doesn't work if i launch jupyter notebook from windows start/search menu

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to change the default directory that Jupyter Notebook opens on. My OS is windows 10. I changed the c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir setting in the jupyter_notebook_config.py file. This works when I open Jupyter Notebooks thru Anaconda navigator, i.e. if I open Anaconda Navigator first and then launch Jupyter Notebooks from there.

MY problem is that when I launch jupyter notebook by typing it in the windows start/search menu, it does not open in the directory specified in the c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir setting in the jupyter_notebook_config.py file.

Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you typing it in windows search box, you run the shortcut actually, even you had edit `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir` setting, just right click the the shortcut and open the files location or edit the shortcut directly
ex: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)\Jupyter Notebook.lnk`,

right click the properties of shortcut, you will see the target is

```
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py "C:\Users\user",
```

delete the default value to

```
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py
```

and run it, it will get the `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir` setting